# how to return only filter passed images from the list

Tags: python

Suppose we have a function `processed_filter_description(a, b, c)` which takes 3 parameters.

- a = user input description
- b = file extensions for potential images (jpg, gif),
- c = the list of all the images (`['image1.jpg', 'image1.gif', 'image2.jpg', 'image2.gif', 'image3.jpg', 'image3.gif']`)

The function checks the description variable (a), and checks the matching extension or image type variable (b), and return the matching criteria from the images list (c).

Comment: need question. Write at least one sentence with question mark at the end!

Comment: I tried to clarify it as much as possible, but it still isn't particularly clear. Please add an explicit question, tell us what the description is, how you want to filter, etc. to the question.

Comment: I am voting to close this, because this is not a real question and it is difficult to say what is being asked here. Write a question.

Comment: This looks to be a reasonable question about how to write a filename filter for a typical style of naming image collections.  There isn't an explicit question, but I presume the OP wants to know how to write a filtering function like that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you spec correctly, it looks something like this:

```
>>> def processed_filter_description(desc, exts, all_images):
        result = []
        for image in all_images:
            base, ext = os.path.splitext(image)
            if base.startswith(desc) and ext in exts:
                result.append(image)
        return result

>>> filenames = ['rainbow1.gif', 'sunset1.jpg', 'rainbow1.idx', 
                 'sunset2.jpg', 'rainbow2.jpg', 'sunset3.gif']
>>> processed_filter_description('rainbow', ('.jpg', '.gif'), filenames)
['rainbow1.gif', 'rainbow2.jpg']
```

Comment: thankss Raymond .this was very helpful.. iwas looking for the same thing